# PHP Email Script - whenever i add id?= text after it getting starting 2 letters truncated

Tags: javascript, php, email, truncated

I'm creating Mobile App using Ionic. In the App, I have written some logic for lost your password functionality. There is 1 Email field from where the user can add their registered email and get some link to reset their password. please check the code below

```
http://proittechnology.com/dev/stylr/changePasswordEdit.php?id=
```

After =(equal to) sign I'm adding $email variable which checks user variable into DB and grabs their data.please check below code

```
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $email = $request->email;

     if ($email != "") {
        echo "Server returns: " . $email;
    }
    else {
        echo "Empty username parameter!";
    }

        $headers = "From: resume@harshadpatil.com" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;


        $message = 'http://proittechnology.com/dev/stylr/changePasswordEdit.php?id='.$email;
        $send = mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers );
        if ($send)
        $mailReturns = "Mail sent successfully.";
        else
        $mailReturns = "Mail sent failed.";


        echo $mailReturns;
```

my concern is whenever I sent the email to OUTLOOK after =(equal to sign) starting 2 letters of variable $email is getting truncated and in Gmail =(equal to sign) is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing email in URL then try passing email as `urlencode($email)`

Hope this will help.

Comment: here is code
`$message = 'http://proittechnology.com/dev/stylr/changePasswordEdit.php?id='.urlencode($email);`

Comment: and output
?idwww.harshad.info%40gmail.com

Comment: after id no = sign and @ change to %40

Comment: Not understood your question.

Comment: when i included `urlencode($email)` and tested code via sending an email and I receive URL http://proittechnology.com/dev/stylr/changePasswordEdit.php?idwww.harshad.info%40gmail.com
in the email also there is not = sign after id

Comment: There must be some single or double quote issue. Can you please post full code after your modification ?

Comment: `$message = 'http://proittechnology.com/dev/stylr/changePasswordEdit.php?id='.urlencode($email);`

Comment: What value you are passing in email ?

Comment: I'm passing email id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127944/discussion-between-jay-gosai-and-harshad-patil).